# showing text along with checkbox in checkbox column in datagridview

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I want to show the text along with checkbox in every cell in checkbox column in a datagridview.Is it possible?If it is,Please help me with the sample code.

Thanx in advance

I want in c# please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something as below for the text of checkbox

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server"
                            AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged"
                            Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved")) %>'
                            Text='<%# Eval("Approved").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Approved " : " Not Approved " %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>                   
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind

```
((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkStatus")).Text="abc";
```

Comment: @sushma - what do you mean by C#. in code behind file you need to search check box and than you have to assign text something like ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkStatus")).Text="abc";